# Error while attempting to import list in constant contact in drupal 7, geting error invalid Status Code 400

Tags: drupal, constantcontact

when i try to import csv file  in constant contact module drupal 7 i am getting error "Your subscribers could not be imported: Invalid status code 400".
my drupal version is 7.58

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This is not a code-writing service, but if you post your existing code we can see where you're going wrong and assist you. Please consider expanding your question and adding a relevant code examples.

Comment: Consider your CSV or some values in your CSV are the problem. Hard to tell from the minimal info we have.